# Scala: strange behavior in `for` pattern matching for None case

Tags: scala, for-loop, pattern-matching

Strange behavior in `for` cycle pattern matching:

```
scala> val a = Seq(Some(1), None)
a: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None)

scala> for (Some(x) <- a) { println(x) }
1

scala> for (None <- a) { println("none") }
none
none
```

Why in second example two output `'none'` produced? Maybe this example is synthetic and not practical, but such behavior is not expectable. Is this bug or feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you know, it is a bug:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9324

```
scala> val vs = Seq(Some(1), None)
vs: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None)

scala> for (n @ None <- vs) println(n)
None
```

The spec in umambiguous:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops

Compare midstream assignment, which does not exhibit the bug:

```
scala> for (v <- vs; None = v) println(v)
scala.MatchError: Some(1) (of class scala.Some)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:9)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:9)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: If using workaround from this issue, it works: `scala> for (n @ None <- a) println("none")`
produces `none` output

Comment: Ha, I also used `n`, but you typed faster.

Comment: BTW, you can uncheck the green, so people don't think that's how Scala is supposed to work. I linked the issue here, so the Scala folks don't think people don't waste time on these minor issues.

Comment: BTW, example with `for(Some(x) <- a)` is present in Odersky book (SE), but there are no example with `None`

Answer (score 4):

That's because `None` was interpreted as a name of variable:

```
scala> for (None <- a) { println(None) } 
Some(1)
None
```

Here is simplified example without `for`:

```
scala> val None = 5
None: Int = 5

scala> val Some(a) = Some(5)
a: Int = 5
```

Comment: `for(_ <- a.collect{case None => ()})`

Comment: `for(x <- a if x.isEmpty) {println("none")}`

Comment: Why isn't that a bug? The thing to the left of the <- is just a pattern. It translates to `case None` (filtered because not irrefutable).

Comment: The `val None` is different because the definition form is different from the `val pattern` form.

Comment: @som-snytt I found that the only difference between `for` (Pattern1) and `val` (Pattern2) in [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html) is `_` acceptance. however, example in your answer shows that spec was violated at least for `Pattern1 =` as it shows different behaviour.

Comment: syntax != semantics. There's an issue to treat `x: Int` in `for` as filter, for example. In generator, refutable pattern means you must filter.